# flutterfire realtime database a children to dynamic list

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new on flutter. Now i am trying to get a children from realtime database to dynamic list. and with that list i need count them and create box. but when i try that i get all datasnapshot in one box with datakey.

My future class:

```
Future<dynamic> getdata() async { 
  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("Categories");
  final snapshot = await ref.get();
  if (snapshot.exists) {
       entry.add(snapshot.value);
   print(entry);
  } else {
      print('No data available.');
  } 
}
late List<dynamic> entry =[];
```

my output

> I/flutter (13624): [{-N3lX7tMzVVT7gqUF_1q: deneme, -N3lX9bwkr3X6J3wfHfq: deneme1, -N3lXAwEnNKQ1WcA4Vw2: deneme2, -N3lXFEq5RV5HXkfHiVF: deneme3}]

so i want this one by one not in one line and just data not key. with that i will create box and write there .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to [loop over the children](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) of the snapshot you get from Firebase, which you can do with:

```
final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("Categories");
final snapshot = await ref.get();
if (snapshot.exists) {
  snapshot.children.forEach((child) { // 
            // 
    entry.add(child.value);
  })
  print(entry);
} else {
  print('No data available.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have put your snapshot data inside `Map` like:

```
Future<dynamic> getdata() async {
      final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("Categories");
      final snapshot = await ref.get();
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> categories = snapshot.value;
        categories.values.forEach((value) {
          print(value);
        });
      } else {
        print('No data available.');
      }
    }
```

Here you can get all data one by one. (You can use it by adding inside the `List`).